# chartjs sample can't install

Tags: node.js, chart.js

As picture mention, I follow offical website download and enter ***pnpm ci***.

But I cant install properly. What should I do?

version info
npm@9.5.1
pnpm@8.6.6

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/information.html

[image]